# Is there a way to name graphql requests in the devtool network tab?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, devtools

I'm using apollo as my client and I run plenty of queries and mutations on my app. I was wondering if there is a way to have each of my query/mutation displayed by its name (eg. getProduct) instead of all showing as "graph" in my network tab? I'm on Brave (Chromium).

It would make debugging easier if I didn't have to click on each one and check the headers or the response to identify which query or mutation this request corresponds to.

Here's how it currently shows in my devtools:

[network tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Eu2R.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: my company somehow implemented a requestAlias which makes the path look like
v1 (requestAlias) still trying to figure out how to do this by default with my operationName by default...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way but here the minimal code I could do to make it.

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  HttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
} from '@apollo/client';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: MY_BASE_URL });

const namedLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext(() => ({
      uri: `${MY_BASE_URL}?${operation.operationName}`,
    })
  );
  return forward ? forward(operation) : null;
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([namedLink, httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

You'll have to name your query :

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

const QUERY = gql`
  query QueryName {
    ...
  }
`;
```

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 3):

`uri` prop of `HttpLink` can accept function which have `operation` as an arg
so it can be done like this as well:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: (operation) => `${MY_BASE_URL}?${operation.operationName}` });
```